# I'm attempting to create a function in python, but I don't think I'm properly understanding how to do it

Tags: python, function

I'm creating a function to work out the area of a triangle. I have the actual code done because it's quite simple, but I don't know how to implement it into a function.

This is what I have up to now.

```
height = int(input("how tall is the triangle?"))

base = int(input("how long is the base of the triangle?"))

prtwaythre = height * base

area = prtwaythre / 2

print("the area is",area)
```

I have tried to implement it into a function by doing this:

```
def trianglearea():
    prtwaythre = height * base
    area = prtwaythre / 2
    print("the area is",area)
    return
```

and

```
if choice == "1":
    height = int(input("what is the height of the triangle?"))
    base == int(input("what is the length of the base?"))
    trianglearea(height,base)
```

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

Edit: I've realised that my issue now lies with my option choice list, but i cannot notice where I've gone wrong with it either. Can you?

```
while True:
        try:
            print("To select a function please choose from below")
            print("1. area of a triangle")
            print("2. area of a circle")
            print("3. circumferance of a circle")
            print("4. calculate the mean")
            print("5. percentage change")
            print("6. perimeter of a shape")
            print("7. square root")
            print("8. times by a power")
            choice = int(input("To select a function please choose from above"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("enter a valid option")
```

Comment: You declared your function to not take any parameters and then try to pass in 2 when calling it - that can't work - try `def trianglearea(height, base):` instead of `def trianglearea():` (also you should not put `return` at the end of a function if you don't intend to return anything)

Comment: I just tried that and I'm getting nothing but my initial choice list and my input option. Nothing else appears.

Comment: also you have == instead of = in your assigning to base, at least in the code posted

Answer (score 0):

You have a few minor issues. First, when you write a function, you have to specify which arguments it takes. You can either do this with keyword arguments, or required named arguments.

```
def trianglearea(height, base):
    prtwaythre = height * base
    area = prtwaythre / 2
    print("the area is",area)
    return
```

would be the easiest way of doing this, but another option is something like:

```
def trianglearea(height=1, base=):
    prtwaythre = height * base
    area = prtwaythre / 2.0
    print("the area is",area)
    return
```

A second issue here is that you are using `==` for assignment.

```
base = int(input("what is the length of the base?"))
```

instead of

```
base == int(input("what is the length of the base?"))
```